# Django: 400 bad request syntax - what does this message mean?

Tags: django, http, hex, ascii, http-status-code-400

I am using django to build a simple website. When you type the base address (which for now is `127.0.0.1:8000/`), I use django to show a view which does some checks and redirects you based on your user privileges. (If you have admin privileges, you go to `/admin`, if you don't you go to `/home`, and if you aren't logged in you go to `/login`.)

When I make that HTTP request, I get redirected *as I should* but I also see the following two errors in my django log:

1. code 400, message Bad request syntax `('\x16\x03\x01\x00\x95\x01\x00\x00\x91\x03\x01N\xaa\x9c\x08\x96\x7f\x92\xe9Z\x925\xcaY4\xa6\xa5\xab\xf2\x16\xfaT\x89\xe7\x8a\xc3\x99J)6\xfb\xc44\x00\x00H\xc0')`
2. `"??N????Z?5?Y4?????T??ÙJ)6??4H?" 400 -`

I translated the hex in the first one to be (spaces added for legibility): `SYN ETX NUL NUL U SOH NUL NUL Q ETX NUL N 170 156 X r 246 STX 141 214 ? 143 EOT FS j 142 223 s 241 220 < 185 \ \ m 242 &`

I can certainly see why the server wouldn't like that as a request, but I have no idea where it's coming from.

Any ideas?

Thanks very much.

==============

Here is the code for the view:

```
def index(request):
    user = request.user
    admin_courses = []

    if (user.is_authenticated()):
        u_id = user.getUserId()
        my_enrollment = Enrollment.objects.filter(user_id=u_id)
        admin_enrollment = my_enrollment.filter(type="ADMIN")
        for enr in admin_enrollment:
            course = Course.objects.get(id=enr.getCourseId())
            admin_courses.append(course)
        if (len(admin_courses)>0):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
```

Comment: Maybe you should show the code for the view.

Comment: have you tried appending a trailing slash to your redirects?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't change anything. Good idea, though.

Comment: Bad request can also occur when we send empty data. I got this error when I was unknowingly sending an empty array in the requests when it should have been a non-empty one. Took a while to figure it out

Answer (score 107, accepted):

To address your actual question, this occurs if you're trying to access the django server over https. Switch back to http and that error will disappear.

Answer (score 5):

I get this kind of error when I run:

```
manage.py runserver ...
```

instead of:

```
manage.py runfcgi ...
```

because I'm behind Nginx.

When you use runserver, it is listening for standard http web requests. When you use runfcgi, it is listening for a different type of request, using fastcgi protocol instead of plain http.

Comment: `python3 manage.py runfcgi 0.0.0.0:8001
Unknown command: 'runfcgi'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.`

Answer (score 3):

You could refactor this maintenance middleware to achieve the result, because it checks the user status BEFORE processing content requests, which seems more djangonostic..

```
import settings
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


class MaintenanceModeMiddleware(object):
    """
    Maintenance mode for django

    If an anonymous user requests a page, he/she is redirected to the
    maintenance page.
    """
    def process_request(self, request):

        is_login = request.path in (
            settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL,
            settings.LOGIN_URL,
            settings.LOGOUT_URL,
            settings.MAINTENANCE_PATH,
        )
        if (not is_login) and settings.MAINTENANCE and (not request.user.is_authenticated()):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.MAINTENANCE_PATH)
        return None
```

Comment: You're absolutely right; that's a better django strategy. Thanks!